# Should I Tape These Interior Foam Board Seams?

Tags: insulation, garage, pest-control

[image: Garage wall foam board]

As you can see in the picture, I’ve begun opening up the walls in my garage. Plan is to insulate with Rockwool and eventually add a mini split. I live in a dry, hot climate and hope to cool the space enough to use it as a shop during the hot summers.

Also trying to seal out as much of the desert wildlife as possible.

I’ve discovered that the walls are only foam board covered with stucco; no sheathing or anything else on the exterior that I can see through the daylight gaps.

Removing the stucco to bolster the exterior is a bigger project than I can take on at the moment (though perhaps down the road). For now I’d like to do everything I can to seal the gaps and cracks from the inside, in order to improve insulation and keep out wildlife as much as possible.

I plan to use spray foam on the larger gaps and caulk on the others, and I’m wondering, should I also tape these horizontal foam board seams, and/or do anything else with them? I’m not sure whether it’s common to tape board seams from the inside, or whether doing so would have any value, but I want to do everything I can that’ll help while the wall is open.

Open to any suggestions about sealing / taping those boards or anything else I should do to accomplish my goals here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd use foam for *all* the joints. Spray foam can be controlled in a small bead and forced into narrow gaps, and if you're going to tape the joints anyway, caulk doesn't do much for you. It's not a great insulator. Foam would do much better by expanding through the existing panels' depth.

Then the question is whether you need a vapor barrier at that location in the wall. If you're going to add insulation, you probably want any vapor barrier *inside* that, not outside it. The cool side is where condensation occurs, and your activity and respiration/perspiration is where most of the moisture will come from.

I would probably skip the tape and add a poly sheeting to the interior *if* that's advisable in your climate. With it being warm and dry you may just want to let the moisture naturally propagate outward. Check with local experts (builders, inspection offices) to determine best practice, and consider your actual usage expecations.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will skip the caulk and use spray foam on all the joints as you’ve suggested, then tape. 

I’m seeing that vapor barriers are not recommended in my area, but I’ll ask some local experts before I put up new drywall, just to be sure.